# "Hello world" to pixels -- everything between OS, driver, and hardware (CPU, GPU, PCIe, USB-C to display)

Tags: drivers, usb, cpu, display, gpu

Can someone explain "Hello World!" in relation to the modern stack of software and hardware on a modern Linux or Unix machine? Doing a `$ strace` on the binary generated by following helloworld.c program ends in `write()` system call. I would like someone to guide us wannabe-experts about all interaction that occurs between OS, loaded device drivers, and hardware like CPU, GPU, PCIe and USB-C port (connected to an external display) when bytes "Hello World!" are copied from helloworld program's virtual memory. It would be good to know who the initiators of various software and hardware transactions are, how they interact, like interrupts, bus transactions, etc.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("Hello World!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note: This question might appear too broad in someways, but it is actually very focussed. It just asks about the flow of 12 bytes of "Hello World!" from our helloworld program's virtual memory to the USB-C port connected to a display.

Answer (score 1):

X11:

Program -> Virtual Console -> Terminal Application -> Terminal Application calls GTK/Qt render routines -> X11 render -> Xorg's compositor (optionally) -> Xorg's GPU driver (normally KMS nowadays) -> kernel GPU driver -> Display

Wayland:

Program -> Virtual Console -> Terminal Application -> Terminal Application calls GTK/Qt render routines -> Wayland's buffer -> Wayland compositor ->  kernel GPU driver -> Display

Comment: It's kind of more complex at the begining, isn't it? With […] denoting what is happening in userland without necessarily switching to kernel mode in between  [program -> write to stdout]  -> pty (slave) -> pty controller -> pyt (master) <-> [returning read from pty -> calling into-buffer-rendering routines -> sending off RPC to X.org server] -> kernel IPC / domain sockets -> [X.org driver -> write to memory and call into GPU driver] -> kernel side of GPU driver

Comment: and of course it gets way less clear once you realize that, huh the terminal application actually holds a handle to an OpenGL context and is allowed to directly write into the GPU's memory, and compositing happens on the GPU hardware, and callbacks fly in all directions…

Comment: It's a lot more complicated if we go into the deep details :-) It's just a surface level answer which I'll gladly remove once someone volunteers to write the whole shebang. And I've not mentioned HW interactions at all which will bloat the answer even further but I'm not even sure it's humanly possible to write down the whole chain of events (we also have kernel CPU scheduling/prioritization/etc). I guess it'd be better just to fire up a VM and record what happens in between two events and then ... whoa, the amount of disassembly required will be insane.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks! At a high level, I would also want to understand what transactions go on system bus (like PCIe) and what pieces of hardware/software would initiate them for moving the bytes of "Hello World" :)

Comment: @codepoet hardware functionality is out of scope for a Unix/Linux stackexchange site. You might not realize it, but what you're asking for is very broad. What you're asking is a 13 week (full semester) lecture on "computer architecture". Look for MIT opencourseware videos on that topic. (yes, a full semester course is the amount of very high level stuff.) Just to give you an insight: I'm pretty sure that the string "Hello World" never gets moved across PCIe, USB or of the other interfaces you mentioned.